# IOS: problem with NSOrderedDescending and NSOrderedAscending

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdate

I want to compare dates and I use this code

in one example date values for my date are:
date1 = 6/06/2011
date2 = 8/06/2011

if dateSelected = 7/06/2011 it's all ok, but if dateSelected = 6/06/2011 or dateSelected = 8/06/2011 the code don't entry inside my "if", why???

```
if (([dateSelected compare:date1] == NSOrderedDescending) &&
                ([dateSelected compare:date2]== NSOrderedAscending))
            {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDates represent a point in time since 1/1/2000 00:00 UTC.  So all of those dates have time components. `-compare:` compares date and time.

Presumably, you really want to check if the date selected is between 6/6/2011 00:00 and 9/6/2011 00:00.  Also you probably want the date 6/6/2011 00:00 to count as in the range.  So you need something like

```
NSComparisonResult compareStart = [date1 compare: selectedDate]; // date1 is 6/6/2011 00:00
NSComparisonResult compareEnd = [date2 compare: selectedDate];   // date2 is 9/6/2011 00:00

if ((compareStart == NSOrderedAscending) || (compareStart == NSOrderedSame)
    && (compareEnd == NSOrderedDescending))
{
    // date is in the right range
}
```

Comment: I have ever this warning "incompatible pointer type sending NSDate to parameter of type NSNumber"

Comment: @blackguardian: You would only get that if you were trying to compare the date against a number.  How have you set up date1, date2 and the selected date?

Comment: the result in console is:

2011-06-06 10:31:48.423 Project[173:707] date1:2011-06-06 08:30:57 +0000
2011-06-06 10:31:48.429 Project[173:707] date2:2011-06-08 00:00:00 +0000
2011-06-06 10:31:48.432 Project[173:707] dateSelected:2011-06-07 08:30:37 +0000

Comment: @blackguardian: I don't understand.  What do you mean by "nothing"? Are you expecting a comment on the log?

Comment: it's ok but with your "if" when data1 = selectedDate or date2 = selectedDate it don't entry in the "if"

Comment: With my code, if `date1 == selectedDate` it's in the range, that's why I do the compare with `NSOrderedSame`.  date2 is the first date you **don't** want in the range which is why I don't compare it with `NSOrderedSame`

Comment: then I want that my code entry in to the "if" when date1 = selectedData or date2 = selectedData and of course when they are within the range

Comment: @blackguardian: in that case, add a comparison to `NSOrderedSame` for `compareEnd` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (([date1 compare:dateSelected] == NSOrderedAscending) &&
                ([date2 compare:dateSelected]== NSOrderedDescending))
            {}
```

Comment: not I have a warning "incompatible pointer type sending NSDate to parameter of type NSNumber"

Comment: I was trying to take advantage of the difference between [a compare:b] vs. [b compare:a] to take care of your requirement for the range to be inclusive of the bounds... but I think JeremyP's answer is a better one anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem than @blackguardian :

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSNumber *' with an lvalue of type 'NSDate *'
```

On something like this:

```
NSDate* oldDate = [NSDate date];
BOOL older = ([[NSDate date] compare:oldDate] == NSOrderedDescending);
```

I do not know why, but you need to cast the "[NSDate date]" into "NSDate*".
This is working:

```
NSDate* oldDate = [NSDate date];
BOOL older = ([[(NSDate*)[NSDate date] compare:oldDate] == NSOrderedDescending);
```