# Check if the given date time is between two others date time in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdate

I am trying to figure out the way to check my date time is between two others date time, for example I am getting current time from my server as "Mar 16 2015 14:17" so I want to check that whether this date time is between two others date time range as "Feb 4 2015 08:00-09:00" or not.

Comment: Do you struggle with date formats parsing or actual comparsion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470236/check-if-a-date-is-between-two-days-in-iphone

Comment: Check my answer. In which if isDateCheck return YES then date between two date else No between two date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try that code if you have three `NSDate` instances:

```
NSDate *beginDate, *endDate, *checkDate;
if ([beginDate laterDate:checkDate] == checkDate &&
    [checkDate laterDate:endDate] == endDate) {
    //checkDate in between beginDate and endDate
}
```

For date parsing use the following:

```
NSString *inputRange = @"Feb 4 2015 08:00-09:00";
NSRange firstRange = NSMakeRange(0, inputRange.length - 6);
NSString *firstDate = [inputRange substringWithRange:firstRange];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm";
NSDate *beginDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:firstDate];
NSString *secondDate = [inputRange substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, inputRange.length - 11)];
secondDate = [secondDate stringByAppendingString:[inputRange substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(inputRange.length - 5, 5)]];
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:secondDate];
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, actually I am new for this logic @Azat, Should i need to do date format parsing before comparing it?

Comment: Yes you should parse your string dates into `NSDate` objects. Do you have exactly the following format for interval or do you have two separate date strings? `Feb 4 2015 08:00-09:00`

Comment: Okey.. can you tell me for my scenario, how can i parse with date time period 'Feb 4 2015 08:00-09:00'?

Comment: @AnandGautam I added to my answer parsing code, but it _highly_ depends on your format string

Comment: Thanks @Azat, I am trying your code in my app, please give me some time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following class method

```
+ (BOOL)checkDate:(NSDate*)dateToCheck startingDate:(NSDate*)startingDate endDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{
    BOOL returnValue;

    if ([startingDate compare:endDate]==NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        returnValue = [dateToCheck compare:endDate]==NSOrderedAscending && [dateToCheck compare:startingDate]==NSOrderedDescending;

    }
    else if ([startingDate compare:endDate]==NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        returnValue = [dateToCheck compare:startingDate]==NSOrderedAscending && [dateToCheck compare:endDate]==NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else
    {
    returnValue = [dateToCheck compare:startingDate]==NSOrderedSame && [dateToCheck compare:endDate]==NSOrderedSame;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Current date :**

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"-- %@",currentDate);
```

**Start date :**

*// Start Date - 2015-03-12 00:00:58 +0000*

```
NSString *stringStartDate = @"2015-03-12 00:00:58";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateStart = [formatter dateFromString:stringStartDate];
```

**End date :**

// End Date - 2015-03-20 00:00:58 +0000

```
NSString *stringEndDate = @"2015-03-20 00:00:58";
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateEnd = [formatter1 dateFromString:stringEndDate];
```

**Function to check date between two date or not**

```
BOOL isDateCheck = [self isDate:currentDate inRangeFirstDate:dateStart lastDate:dateEnd];
```

**Function**

```
- (BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date inRangeFirstDate:(NSDate *)firstDate lastDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {
    return [date compare:firstDate] == NSOrderedDescending &&
    [date compare:lastDate]  == NSOrderedAscending;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kirit Modi for your answer.